# Matlab - Multiple 2D plots along a 3rd dimension

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, surf

I'm trying to plot many 2D plots (x,y).

But...
each 2D plot is for a constant z.

So really my data is (x,y,z) but not z(x,y), which I believe are the requirements for using the "surf" command.

Could anyone help with this?

Example, 
x = velocity
y = drag

I have multiple runs of y(x) for a constant temperature, z.

I just want to plot each (x,y) along a 3rd axis, temperature z.

Ideally I'd also want some sort of contour between the (x,y) plots so I can show the peaks/troughs etc.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Imagine I took multiple measurements of drag at a single velocity - does it make sense to plot those in 2D?  You could use "run number" as your third axis (with `plot3`, for example), but it may be clearer to just overlay plots in 2D and look at the variability between runs that way.

Comment: Thank you very much. 

The reason that I want to use a 3D plot is that it can get quite difficult to interpret the various lines, especially if each "run" changes the lines significantly. I think it is very hard to clearly show many time traces on the same 2D plot; it often become confusing to pick out the trend from the plots by looking at it. Maybe there is an nice way to do it..

A plot3 is very close to what I want to do. However, I would still like to be able to connect the different "runs" with some type of contour, but I take it a mesh must first be generated.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the runs are not independent (there is some trend over multiple runs) then it may make sense to use `surf`.  You then need to construct your data such you have an X,Y, and Z - in this case I'd suggest you use the drag measurements as your Z (height).

Assuming that you have all the drag/velocity data in  `drag` and `velocity` which are both of size [data points x number of runs]:

```
% construct matrix of run numbers
runs = repmat(1:numruns, [1, datapoints]); 
runs = reshape(runs, datapoints, numruns);

% plot and label
surf(runs,velocity,drag);
xlabel('runs')
ylabel('velocity')
zlabel('drag')
```